# Parse Query returns ALL results

Tags: android, linq, xamarin, parse-platform

I'm writing a Xamarin Android app which is using Parse.com as the backend. I'm running a query against a Parse Class called `Beacons`, of which one of the columns is a `Pointer` to another class called `BeaconCat`.

I'm therefore using two queries as shown below, but when it returns the data, it lists ALL of the categories within the `BeaconCat` class, not just the one which matches the initial query.

I'm expecting just one category, not all 13 of them. Any idea why?

```
// First query on class 1.
var innerQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("Beacons"); 
innerQuery.WhereEqualTo("minor", minor);

// Query on class 2 which passes in first query.
var newQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("BeaconCat"); 
newQuery.WhereMatchesQuery("Category", innerQuery);

IEnumerable<ParseObject> Myresults = await newQuery.FindAsync();

foreach (var result in Myresults)
{
    var category = result.Get<string>("Category");

    Console.WriteLine ("Category " + category);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are the results of innerQuery what you're expecting?

Comment: I solved this problem in the end [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428924/parse-query-on-pointer-column?noredirect=1#comment39670742_25428924

Thanks.